# Sum of reciprocal of zeroes of zeta function

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

The sum of reciprocal of zeroes of riemann zeta function converges conditionally that if they are paired as $\rho $ and $1-\rho$ My question is if the sum still converges if they are paired as $\rho$ and $\rho$ conjugate .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. $\textbf{}$ $\textbf{}$ $\textbf{}$

Comment: Both convergence arguments rely on the fact that $\sum_\rho 1/(\Im\rho)^2$ converges, which is a consequence of the upper bound $cT\log T$ for the number of zeros with imaginary part bounded in absolute value by $T$. Then, note $1/\rho+1/\bar\rho = 2\Re\rho/((\Re\rho)^2+(\Im\rho)^2) \le 2/(\Im\rho)^2$.

Comment: I fixed the awkward spacing before the period. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not at all. The awkwardness should all come from the content!